# Remotely controling my cctv server with my mobile devices.. Android

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, android

I have a cctv server 192.168.0.155 connected to my main router. I am trying to connect to it from my tablet that is connected to my network via an old wireless router that I have acting as an AP. The wireless router has a different ip range, 192.168.1.xxx.
How do I setup my network so I can control my server.
And can I change the ip range of the AP to the same as my original router?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off DHCP on the old wireless router acting as an AP. Might want to set old AP IP address as an IP within the main router network, ex: 192.168.0.2

This will cause all wireless clients on old AP to get a DHCP network address from the main router & allow devices to talk to one another